# Washing a waxed car?

Tags: detailing, wax

So.. I'm going to wax a car for the first time. From what I hear a wax lasts from 3 weeks to several months (wax+sealant combi product), depending on car usage and product.

- What if I want to wash the car before the wax life-time has ended. Can I just do regular (two bucket) wash? Are waxes normally resistant to this?

Never dealt with waxing a car before, so I'm quite oblivious :)

Comment: See this question and, most usefully, the answer: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/61163/10976

Comment: @solarmike did you mean to link to another question? That's talking about claying which is a different process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep to wash a waved car just use two bucket method and a gentle shampoo like Megs Hyperwash, avoid using anything with wax properties itself like "Wash and Wax" and it's ilk. Washing is normal and waxes are designed to be washed, it's actually a good opportunity to check how well it's still sheeting/beading. Washing also helps prevent contaminates such as tree sap and bird mess from damaging the wax coat.

To maintain the wax coat at its best optionally give it a spray with a quick detailer and buff with a microfibre after washing, this will help keep the finish even and protected.